# Hyphenation in MDPI class

Tags: hyphenation, mdpi

I'm writing in an article in the MDPI class file (available [here](http://www.mdpi.com/authors/latex)).

In my preamble, I have 
`\usepackage[american]{babel}`. Still, I don't get any hyphenation in my document. Does anyone know why?

Comment: I see that the `hyphenat` package is loaded in the mdpi.cls file. This probably explains it, but it still seems odd.

Comment: loaded with option `[none]` so this seems to be a design choice. It's even documented with a comment: `%Now: no hyphenation what so ever`

Comment: Indeed, I'm also considering it a design choice now. I've put the question to MDPI and will provide the answer when available. It's the [editing guidelines](http://www.mdpi.com/authors/english-editing) that made me think hyphenation was allowed, because it's not mentioned there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone with the same question stumbles on this post:

From latex@mdpi.com:

> Yes, this is intended that hyphenation is turned off in the mdpi.cls
>   file.